# What API to use for pulling xml feed files from Wordpress and uploading them to Facebook?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a few Facebook feeds on Wordpress that are being generated by Woo Feed, After I generate them, I upload the XML files to Facebook.

I guess my question is, is there a Facebook API I can use to do this for me? Preferably one that can pull XML data from WP then upload it to FB.
I've looked at the Facebook Graph API and the public feed API but I don't think those would do the trick because graph only pulls posts, images and a couple of other things, but not XML files, correct me if I'm wrong.

I know my question is a bit out there but I rarely work with feeds so any advice is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check the right API ... this is Marketing API, not Graph. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-feed-schedule/

Comment: @CBroe thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.